# Checkboxes don't show

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that suppose to copy column titles from a file and add those titles as checkboxess to a checklist. But when I execute the code it will copy the column titles but it does not create check boxes. Any idea why it doesn't?

```
 If sj = True Or ji = True Then
    For j = 1 To 199
         If Trim(wks1.Cells(4, j).Value) = "" Then
            titlesj = j - 1
            Exit For
        End If
            jTitles(j - 1) = wks1.Cells(4, j).Value
     Next

     j = 1

     ' Add column titles from files into the listbox as checkboxes
     For j = 0 To titlesj
        Sheet1.ListBox1.AddItem jTitles(j)
        Sheet1.ListBox3.AddItem jTitles(j)
     Next
     wb1.Close
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... set the ListStyle and MultiSelect properties for both "Listbox1" and "ListBox3" to "1".  Place the following before both loops.

```
Sheet1.ListBox1.ListStyle = 1
Sheet1.ListBox1.MultiSelect = 1
Sheet1.ListBox3.ListStyle = 1
Sheet1.ListBox3.MultiSelect = 1
```

Source: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/685957-listbox-with-checkboxes.html

Comment: Thank you very much Whistler. It worked for the first one but not for the second one. Any ways I can go from here. I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Ok, Got it, my bad. I forgot to change the listbox name for the third and fourth listbox. Now it works great. Thank you